# I cannot execute more than one or two insertions in my Room database, for it will simply not persist the data after those

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, observers, android-livedata

Whether it's an insert operation in table X or a delete one from table Y, the issue is that only one operation is being executed and for it to work again I need to re-run my app, making a new APK installation. That is, if I insert in table X and attempt to make another insert in table Y, although it will list in the app, it will not persist in the database.

I have confirmed it by running my application in debug mode and inspecting the database using the [com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database). It is this weird, listing from the database while not being in the database. Then, when running the app one more time, these "ghost data" disappear.

I don't know what to show except for the operations code. The easiest one, a `Student` insertion:

```
fun onClickSaveStudentButton(view: View?) {
    val studentName: String = mEdtStudentName?.text.toString()
    val studentEntry = Student(null, studentName)

    thread { mDb?.studentsDao()?.insert(studentEntry) }

    finish()
}
```

Only one field for the name, and a thread executing the insertion. It sometimes will allow me to insert twice but after it, the same problem will happen. I thought it could be something with `thread`, so I installed `Anko` and made use of `doAsync`, but the problem continues.

This is the DAO function to insert:

```
@Insert
fun insert(data: Student)
```

What is going wrong here? Why's it only allowing me to insert once or twice?

The database class:

```
@Database(entities = [(Schedule::class), (Student::class)], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var sInstance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase = sInstance ?: synchronized(this) {
            sInstance ?: Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                Constants.DATABASE_NAME
            ).build().also {
                sInstance = it
            }
        }
    }

    abstract fun scheduleDao(): ScheduleDao
    abstract fun studentsDao(): StudentDao
}
```

And here, as example, `Student` model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "students")
class Student constructor(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String?
)
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/mfgabriel92/classes-android).

Comment: can you add your model class and database class

Comment: Yes. I've updated the question.

Comment: What primary key do you use? Is it possible that you are inserting rows with the same key causing room to overwrite the original row or abort the insert?

Comment: I am passing `null` when creating it, it is auto generated.

Comment: Also, I had a conflict check to replace, but even though it wasn't replacing but simply not inserting.

Comment: I just tried to use `init` instead of passing the `constructor`, but the same thing happens.

Comment: Someone, please? I cannot solve this. All the codes I see are just like the way I did, yet it happens to me. I added `@Volatile` before the instance variable in `AppDatabase`, but the problem persists.